# Visualizing OpenStreetMap tiling scheme in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, tiling-scheme

OpenStreetmap uses a tiling scheme which is adapted to usual access patterns, as shown in the figure below. I would like to visualize it, as shown in the figure, in QGIS.

Any suggestions on how can I do it?

[image: OpenStreetMap Tiling scheme]

Comment: How are you showing it in OpenLayers?

Comment: The image was not generated by me. You can find it here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220766684_Putting_Pixels_in_Place_A_Storage_Layout_Language_for_Scientific_Data/figures?lo=1

Comment: Feel free to ask about ArcGIS Pro in a separate question. Asking about QGIS and ArcGIS Pro in separate questions makes it easier for you to describe what you have tried and where you are stuck using each.